# Mechanism to upload ARM template into storage

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I want to use [linked templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates) in my ARM deployment model. Every article I've read mentions that the linked template needs to be in an accessible location (such as blob storage).

This works OK if I manually upload the files to storage but I'm looking for a mechanism to upload a template to Storage as part of the build or Deployment process.

I'd hoped to use the `Artifact Storage Account` option but it is unavailable when deploying infrastructure only.

[image]

Is there a built-in method to achieve this or would it require either an extra step such as powershell script or VSTS build step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Artifact Storage Account* option becomes available as soon as you introduce the two parameters _artifactsLocation and _artifactsLocationSasToken into your deployment.

```
  "parameters": {
    "_artifactsLocation": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Auto-generated container in staging storage account to receive post-build staging folder upload"
      }
    },
    "_artifactsLocationSasToken": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Auto-generated token to access _artifactsLocation"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Note, that these 2 parameters are not inherent in ARM but part of a pattern used by the samples scripts in VS and the QuickStart repo, this https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1and https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/az-group-deploy.sh -- follow the pattern documented here (e.g. defaultValues) and that will make the templates more portable: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/1-CONTRIBUTION-GUIDE/best-practices.md#deployment-artifacts-nested-templates-scripts