# How to create ARM linked template when the linked templates are stored locally not in the cloud

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-monitoring

Having a main ARM template and a linked ARM template, is it possible to deploy the resources from VS?

When I try that is says "*The language expression property 'templateLink' doesn't exist, available properties are 
12:40:36 - 'template, parameters, mode, provisioningState*".

Looking it up I found answers that indicate that you have to upload the linked templates somewhere in the cloud but to me it is stupid not being able to do all of your work, including deployment, from VS.

Is there a way to deploy from VS or from a command prompt and all the templates to exist on the local drive?

Comment: The deployproj in VS will do this for you (upload the files) - there is no way to get ARM a link to your c: drive...

Comment: How do I upload the files (child templates) with deployproj?

Comment: The PS1 that's included in the deployproj (which is what the VS UI uses to deploy) will upload the files for you.

Comment: I am sorry, I still cannot make my project's Deploy to upload the child templates. 
Based on your comment here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906732/mechanism-to-upload-arm-template-into-storage) I added _artifacts location and _artifactsLocationSasToken parameters (took the sample from here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/1-CONTRIBUTION-GUIDE/best-practices.md#deployment-artifacts-nested-templates-scripts). 
See the next comment for continuation.

Comment: I reference the child template as advised in the sample. When deploying from VS I selected the default for "Artifacts storage account" field and a new storage account was created. However only the main template, the main parameters file and the PS1 script were uploaded in the blob. I expected to find the child template there too. On my machine the child templated is stored in the "NestedTemplates" folder as advised in the best practices document (above). I cannot find any "NestedTemplates" blob container in the storage account.

Comment: The error I get is "Error: Code=InvalidContentLink; Message=Unable to download deployment content from 'https:/.../"

Comment: Did you add the templates to the project manually?  (e.g. add file) - if so, make sure the Build Action in the file's properties is set to "Content" and the Copy to Output Directory is set to "Copy Always".  You can also try just invoking the PS1 from the cmd line and deploying from source (to test to see if your templates are correct).

Comment: After i set those two properties the "NestedTemplates" folder is created and the child template is uploaded but the deployment still fails with the following error: "Error: Code=InvalidContentLink; Message=Unable to download deployment content from 'https://*******.blob.core.windows.net/NestedTemplates/HelloWorld.json?sv=2017-07-29&sr=...."

Comment: Hmm, this URI misses the name of the blob. This is how i build the uri: ""nestedtemplateUri": "[uri(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), concat('NestedTemplates/HelloWorld.json', parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')))]"". How do i specify the name of the blob in that concat? is there a function that returns the name of the blob?

Comment: OK, this is what I came up with: "nestedtemplateUri": "[uri(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), concat(resourceGroup().name, '-stageartifacts/', 'NestedTemplates/HelloWorld.json', parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')))]" but i don't like that I had to hardcode  "-stageartifacts". Is there a better way?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the Storage Account be deleted after the deployment, cleaning up after the job is done?

Comment: you shouldn't need to append the container name to your template code (that icky feeling you had is correct) - check the deployment in the portal and see what value was passed for the _artifactsLocation parameter - it should have the container name appended to the blob uri - also make sure it has a trailing / - I think the VS script has had a bug in it around that.  See this one: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1 - the storage account isn't deleted, it allows for debugging like this.

Comment: The "_artifactsLocation" parameter in Deployment has the container name. I also added the parameter in template's Output and I can see it there as well that it has the container name

Comment: Can you post/gist the code? (or a smaller sample that can repro what you're seeing)?

Comment: Please take a look here for the code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55112342/arm-nested-templates-artifactlocation-parameter-is-not-populated-correctly-whe

Comment: @bmoore-msft could you add the answer from the other location so I can resolve this question?

Comment: sure... see below.

Comment: Did you mean to add the answer? I don't see your answer below. :)

Comment: It was deleted by a moderator seems answering multiple questions with the same answer is not allowed.  I'm not sure what they expect here so will have to look elsewhere for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy the template completely from VS, it will upload all the linked templates in the cloud and the do the deployment.

See the answer for [this question](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=6AFA387D4C26250B%2163188&id=documents&wd=target%28Technologies%2FOneNote.one%7C118AB879-7B61-4D05-BB1E-47B0D988E180%2FRibbon%7C5CE3A460-FDEC-467D-ABE4-2A4332CB56F5%2F%29%20onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/6afa387d4c26250b/Documents/nd%20Memory/Technologies/OneNote.one#Ribbon&section-id=%7B118AB879-7B61-4D05-BB1E-47B0D988E180%7D&page-id=%7B5CE3A460-FDEC-467D-ABE4-2A4332CB56F5%7D&end).

Answer (score 2):

No, linked templates have to be uploaded to some place available to the ARM engine to fetch them. Or you can just "type" them inline, but thats is pretty tricky due to how they work compared to regular linked templates (hint - dont really use this approach).

What I usually do - upload all the templates with powershell and just reference each other with `url()` function

Comment: Can I ask how you test them before uploading? You need to upload just to test? Then fix and upload again and test again? And what if there is already a working version uploaded there? If you can't test it locally there is a risk that you will overvrite working templates with bad ones. How to restore then?

Comment: I suggest you start a new question, since this is too much to answer in the comments. just ping me on this question and I'll provide an answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59697821/how-to-test-linked-arm-templates